# In PHP, why when I'm casting a var as string into a float I loose the precision?

Tags: php, casting, precision, floating

I query my DB (MYSQL) to get the value of a column "1.10757" I need to convert it into a float, but php round my var to 1. I don't understand why and how to keep the decimals.

```
$query = "SELECT rate_usd_eur FROM production.utils WHERE id = 1";
$USDRate = getQuery($query); // $USDRate = "1.10757" as String
$USDRate = (float)$USDRate ; // $USDRate = 1 as Float <- Why I lost my decimals?
var_dump ($USDRate);
```

Comment: tested, can't reproduce, perhaps the issue is with getQuery() http://ideone.com/axv4BI

Comment: Are you sure it's not your getQuery function? When I do this in my terminal, it works just fine: php -r '$test = "1.1234"; $test2 = (float)$test; var_dump($test2);'

Comment: have a look to your locale settings, any chance your decimal point separator is not a dot?

`$locale_info = localeconv(); echo 'decimal_point=', $locale_info['decimal_point'], '<br/>/n';`

Comment: @Louis Sudre, try to use `$USDRate = floatval($USDRate);` it supposed to check and set the value like it is.

Comment: If you need to do precise calculations with a decimal value, don’t convert to float. Use bcmath functions to avoid rounding errors.

Comment: What does `var_dump($USDRate);` show *before* you cast it?

Comment: Ok, now it's work, thank you for your help. My getQuery() function didn't return a string, but an array with the string inside.